# Stackoverflow exception that occurs through non-recursive function

Tags: java, generics, stack-overflow

I am relatively new to Java Generics and the following two Generic classes represent the Vertex and the Connector involved in Graph data structure.

Connector.java class

```
package ac.lk.iit.algorithmscomplexities.coursework2.datastructure;
public class Connector<E,F> {
    private Vertex<E, F> start, end;    // starting Vertex instance and ending Vertex instance of the Connector
    private F element;  // the data of generic type F to be held by the Vertex connector
    private double value;   // a descriptive value of the connector relative to other connectors depending on the scenario

    /**
     * a protected constructor which creates an instance of Connector class
     * @param start starting Vertex instance of the Connector
     * @param end ending Vertex instance of the Connector
     * @param element data of generic type F to be held by the Vertex connector
     * @param cost descriptive value of the connector relative to other connectors depending on the scenario
     */
    protected Connector(Vertex<E,F> start, Vertex<E,F> end, F element, double cost) {
        this.setStart(start);
        this.setEnd(end);
        this.setElement(element);
        this.setValue(cost);
    }

    /**
     * returns the starting Vertex instance of the Connector
     * @return the starting Vertex instance of the Connector
     */
    protected Vertex<E,F> getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    /**
     * sets the Vertex argument provided to the starting Vertex instance field of the Connector instance
     * @param start the starting Vertex instance of the Connector
     */
    private void setStart(Vertex<E,F> start) {
        if(start != null) {
            this.start = start;
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns the ending Vertex instance of the Connector
     * @return the ending Vertex instance of the Connector
     */
    protected Vertex<E,F> getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    /**
     * sets the Vertex argument provided to the ending Vertex instance field of the Connector instance
     * @param end the ending Vertex instance of the Connector
     */
    private void setEnd(Vertex<E,F> end) {
        if(end != null) {
            this.end = end;
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns the data of generic type F held by the Vertex connector
     * @return the data of generic type F held by the Vertex connector
     */
    protected F getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * sets the data of generic type F to the element instance field of the Vertex connector
     * @param element data of generic type F to be held by the Vertex connector
     */
    private void setElement(F element) {
        if(element != null) {
            this.element = element;
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns a descriptive value of the connector relative to other connectors depending on the scenario
     * @return descriptive value of the connector relative to other connectors depending on the scenario
     */
    protected double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * sets a descriptive value of the connector relative to other connectors depending on the scenario to value instance field of Connector instance
     * @param value a descriptive value of the connector relative to other connectors depending on the scenario
     */
    private void setValue(double value) {
        if(value >= 0) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.element.toString();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if(object instanceof Connector) {
            Connector<E,F> newConnector = (Connector<E, F>)object;
            // since it is a directed graph the start, end of each connector and the data element should be unique
            return ((this.getStart().equals(newConnector.getStart())) && (this.getEnd().equals(newConnector.getEnd())) && (this.getElement().equals(newConnector.getElement())));
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Vertex.java class

```
package ac.lk.iit.algorithmscomplexities.coursework2.datastructure;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Vertex<E,F> {

    private int id;         // a unique id value for each vertex created
    private E dataElement;  // data to be held within a vertex
    private LinkedList<Connector<E, F>> pointers;   // list of references to other Vertices connected

    // keeps track of the number of vertices created during the runtime
    protected static int NUMBER_OF_VERTICES = 0;

    /**
     * a protected constructor which creates an instance of Vertex class with the generic E argument provided
     * @param element the element of generic type E to be assigned to dataElement instance field
     */
    protected Vertex(E element) {
        this.setId(Vertex.NUMBER_OF_VERTICES);
        Vertex.NUMBER_OF_VERTICES++;
        this.setDataElement(element);
        this.pointers = new LinkedList<Connector<E, F>>();
    }

    /**
     * returns the unique Integer id value of the Vertex instance
     * @return the unique Integer id value of the Vertex instance
     */
    protected int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * sets the Integer argument provided to the id instance field of the Vertex instance
     * @param id the Integer argument provided to be set to the id instance field of the Vertex instance
     */
    private void setId(int id) {
        if(!(id < 0)) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns the content of the dataElement instance field of the Vertex instance 
     * @return the content of the dataElement instance field of the Vertex instance
     */
    protected E getDataElement() {
        return dataElement;
    }

    /**
     * sets the argument of generic type E to the dataElement instance field of the Vertex instance
     * @param dataElement the element of generic type E to be assigned to dataElement instance field
     */
    protected void setDataElement(E dataElement) {
        if(dataElement != null) {
            this.dataElement = dataElement;
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns the list of Connector instances associated with a Vertex instance
     * @return the list of Connector instances associated with a Vertex instance
     */
    protected LinkedList<Connector<E, F>> getPointers() {
        return pointers;
    }

    /**
     * adds a new Connector instance starting from this Vertex and ending in the specified Vertex instance
     * @param another the ending Vertex of the Connector
     * @param element the data element of generic type F held by the Connector
     * @param value the list of Connector instances associated with a Vertex instance
     */
    protected void connectTo(Vertex<E,F> another, F element, double value) {
        Connector<E,F> newConnector = new Connector<E,F>(this, another, element, value);

        if(!(this.pointers.contains(newConnector))) {
            this.pointers.add(newConnector);
        }

        LinkedList<Connector<E, F>> anotherList = another.getPointers();
        if(!(anotherList.contains(newConnector))) {
            anotherList.add(newConnector);
        }

        System.out.println("[this vertex]:" + this.pointers);
        System.out.println("[that vertex]:" + another.pointers);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {

        if(object instanceof Vertex) {
            Vertex<E,F> newVertex = (Vertex<E,F>) object;
            if(this.pointers.size() != newVertex.getPointers().size()) {
                return false;
            }
            if(!(this.getDataElement().equals(newVertex.getDataElement()))) {
                return false;
            }
            for(int i = 0 ; i < this.pointers.size() ; i++) {
                if(!(this.pointers.get(i).equals(newVertex.getPointers().get(i)))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertex<String, String> vertex1 = new Vertex<String, String>("Chiranga");
        Vertex<String, String> vertex2 = new Vertex<String, String>("Robin");
        Vertex<String, String> vertex3 = new Vertex<String, String>("Sunethra");
        Vertex<String, String> vertex4 = new Vertex<String, String>("Ananda");

        vertex1.connectTo(vertex2, "John", 0);
        //vertex1.connectTo(vertex3, "Mark", 0);

        //vertex1.connectTo(vertex4, "Rob", 0);

        vertex2.connectTo(vertex3, "James", 0);

        vertex4.connectTo(vertex2, "John", 0);
        vertex4.connectTo(vertex3, "Sean", 0);

        //System.out.println(vertex1.equals(vertex4));
        //System.out.println(vertex1.equals(vertex2));
    }
}
```

The above classes give out a stackoverflowexception when executing the following code segment.

```
vertex4.connectTo(vertex3, "Sean", 0);
```

It is hardly possible to understand the real reason behind the above exception as I am not involving any recursive code sample and because it occurs when I make connections between certain Vertex instances only. Most of the code problems related to the above exception type speaks about recursion but the above one seems to be different.

Why do I always get the mentioned stackoverflow exception?

Please note that the above code sample involving main method was coded for testing purposes.

Comment: Care to share the  actual stack trace? Wild guess: it's the `equals` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`equals` method of `Vertex` class contains :

```
if(!(this.pointers.get(i).equals(newVertex.getPointers().get(i))))
```

where `this.pointers.get(i)` is a `Connector`, so `equals` of `Vertex` calls `equals` of `Connector`.

`equals` of the `Connector` class contains :

```
return ((this.getStart().equals(newConnector.getStart())) && (this.getEnd().equals(newConnector.getEnd())) && (this.getElement().equals(newConnector.getElement())));
```

And since `getStart()` and `getEnd()` are of type `Vertex`, this means `equals` of `Connector` is calling `equals` of `Vertex`.

Therefore a call to `equals` of either `Vertex` or `Connector` may lead to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 4):

Your equals method...

When you do the contains method in connectTo it calls equals on the Connectors to ascertain whether the connector is in the list or not.

The equals method for Connector:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Connector) {
        Connector<E, F> newConnector = (Connector<E, F>) object;
        // since it is a directed graph the start, end of each connector and the data element should be unique
        return ((this.getStart().equals(newConnector.getStart())) && (this.getEnd().equals(newConnector.getEnd())) && (this.getElement().equals(newConnector.getElement())));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Notice how it does equals comparision on getStart() - which is a Vertex. Then Vertex equals:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {

    if (object instanceof Vertex) {
        Vertex<E, F> newVertex = (Vertex<E, F>) object;
        if (this.pointers.size() != newVertex.getPointers().size()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(this.getDataElement().equals(newVertex.getDataElement()))) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.pointers.size(); i++) {
            if (!(this.pointers.get(i).equals(newVertex.getPointers().get(i)))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

So Vertex Equals: calls equals on this.pointers (Connectors).

So in other words your equals methods have a cyclic dependency - they each call the other equals method and thus you get a stack overflow exception.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the stack trace, it's easy to understand where the problem is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at ac.lk.iit.algorithmscomplexities.coursework2.datastructure.Connector.equals(Connector.java:123)
    at ac.lk.iit.algorithmscomplexities.coursework2.datastructure.Vertex.equals(Vertex.java:117)
    at ac.lk.iit.algorithmscomplexities.coursework2.datastructure.Connector.equals(Connector.java:123)
    at ac.lk.iit.algorithmscomplexities.coursework2.datastructure.Vertex.equals(Vertex.java:117)
    at ac.lk.iit.algorithmscomplexities.coursework2.datastructure.Connector.equals(Connector.java:123)
    ...
```

Your `Connector` `equals` method calls `Vertex` `equals` method, which calls `Connector`'s `equals` methods,...